# Capitalize and/or hyphenate "the Start Your Own Business project"?

Tags: style, punctuation, capitalization

I have come across a situation which drives me mad, and I cannot find any satisfying answer in the Oxford Guide to Style, which I tend to follow. The problem concerns the phrase "Start Your Own Business", and when it is used as the name of a project. I'm really confused about two things: capitalization and hyphenation. I've written it in capitals and without hyphens here, but that doesn't mean I prefer it that way. I think I would prefer it like this: the Start-Your-Own-Business project. Any ideas what is recommended here?

Comment: If SYOB Project is somebody else's invention, then use what they use.  If it's your invention, then use whatever capitals and hyphens you like.

Comment: Surely, I cannot use capitals and hyphens in any way I like? For instance, "the start your own business project" is ambiguous, and can refer to starting your own "business project" or a project about starting your own business.

Comment: The project is originally in a foreign language, but I think not simply a matter of copying the style, because different languages can have different styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyphens indicate a compound adjective: *a do-it-yourself project.* The hyphens are to let the reader know that all the hyphenated words belong to one thought.

If you're using capitals to denote a proper name, the hyphens are unnecessary. The caps make it a unit.

Comment: Yes it's a name of a project (unlike your example "a do-it-yourself project" which isn't a name). So I will use capitals without hyphens.